# PodioContact::get_for_app - depreciation whats the alternative?

Tags: php, podio

I am using 'PodioContact::get_for_app' to get info using the api and have had trouble getting to the contacts which have filled in a web form with other api calls (ie the people who fill in the form are not podio users and therefore do not appear on in the org or workspace connections/contacts)

I have noticed that podio creates a profile for them and the information entered is converted to just a profile_id but this id does not match any of the id (user or profile) I have for the orgs/apps/workspace users.

I have found that the only way to get to this list of users and profile ids is to use:

https://developers.podio.com/doc/contacts/get-space-contacts-on-app-79475279

I have tried various other ways to get this list but only get the ones connected to the workspace who have full logins eg:

```
PodioSpaceMember::get_all
PodioContact::get_for_space
PodioContact::get_all
PodioContact::get_for_org
```

I am concerned that this api call is being depreciated as I do not see how to retrieve a list of these users otherwise.

Is there an alternative way to get to a list of these users before this is depreciated?

[image]

Comment: I'm not following your question. Is your webform a contact-type app which has a contact field that people fill in details (name, email, etc.)? And you are asking how to get to this information?

Comment: Yes the form collects contact details from the user - some of the users who use the form are podio users who have a login - other users do not have a login and may only use the form once.

I think podio automatically creates a new podio profile with the Name, Email etc of any users of form for non-authenticated users.

Comment: I have added an image of part of the form.